# Nginx multiple location issues

Tags: nginx

I'm currently trying to break apart 3 applications from one repository into 3, but keeping the url structure, so basically different locations under the same domain have to be delivered by different applications.

What I'm struggling with is that one of the apps needs to be the fallback for non-existent urls, so if the first one doesn't match, and the second one doesn't, then the third should handle the request

The structure I've got is:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/main_site, in here, apart from server_name and logs I've got `include /etc/nginx/subsites-enabled/*`, where I've got 3 configuration files, one for each of the apps.

Each of the 3 config files contains a location block.

I've tried negative lookahead in regex (basically trying to hardcode the urls the other apps handle) but failed.

So, to summarise:

/ and /community should be delivered by /etc/nginx/subsites-enabled/example.org/home (a few perl scripts)

/news should be delivered by /etc/nginx/subsites-enabled/example.org/news (wordpress)

everything else should be delivered by /etc/nginx/subsites-enabled/example.org/app (cake app)

The perl bit works fine. The problem I'm having is that the app is taking over news (probably because it matches .*), I've tried various options (I've been at this for 2 days) but none of them solved all the problems (sometimes static assets wouldn't work, etc).

My configuration is:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.org:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.org;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.log;

    include /etc/nginx/subsites-enabled/example.org/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/subsites-enabled/example.org/home:

```
location = / {
  rewrite ^.*$ /index.pl last;
}

location ~* /community(.*) {
  rewrite ^.*$ /index.pl last;
}

location ~ \.pl {
  root   /var/www/vhosts/home;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/home/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/home/error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_index index.pl;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/vhosts/home$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
}
```

/etc/ngins/subsites-enabled/news

```
location /news {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/news/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/news/error.log debug;

  error_page 404 = /news/index.php;

  root /var/www/vhosts/news;

  index index.php;

  if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
  }

  location ~ \.php {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/vhosts/news$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

/etc/nginx/subsites-enabled/app:

```
location ~ .* {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/app/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app/error.log;

  rewrite_log on;

  index index.php;
  root /var/www/vhosts/app/app/webroot;

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    expires 30d;
    break;
  }

  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
  }

  location ~ \.php {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/vhosts/app/app/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: a) post your config along with some examples of where various redirects (including those for non-existent URLs) should go. b) use [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) with a named location block (using the `@` prefix) that maps to your default app. You can also setup an error_page that maps a 404 to a named location.

Comment: @cyberx86 I added more details and my config

Comment: A quick glance suggests a few things: a) regex matching takes precedence over conventional strings - so your app block will match instead of your news block - try `location ^~ /news`. b) for your app block, you should be able to do `location /` (this is not the same as `location = /`, but should match everything not already matched. c) in some cases (particularly regexes), order does matter - you may want to combine the 3 files into a single file with the blocks in the right order. Also, use try_files instead of `!-e`. Finally see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location.

Comment: I tried pretty much every variation of those, including combining them into a single file (even though they need to be separate as they're deployed separately), none of them work. News just gets handled by the app.

Comment: Well, I think have solved it - a bit trickier than I initially expected - but certainly enjoyable to match wits against. Thanks for the puzzle.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your config, the two relevant ones being:

1. Paths within a location block still include the matched path.
2. Rewrites with 'last' continue by looking through all available locations for a match (they break out of the current location block).

For instance, take the URL example.org/news/test.htm

- The `location /news` block will match it
- The path used is then `/news/test.htm` - this does not change, just because it is in the location block
- Adding the path to the document_root, you get: `/var/www/vhosts/news/news/test.htm`
- Your `if (!-e $request_filename)` statement should capture this non-existent file
- You rewrite the path to `/index.php`
- Since you are using `last` the processes starts over (breaking out of the location block)
- `/index.php` is now captured by the `location /app block`.

The problem mentioned above, with the root directive, is compounded when you go to your app location block. Unlike with the 'news' block, where you could conceivably just remove 'news' from the path (since it will be added back in), you cannot do this for the app path, which ends in 'webroot'.

The solution lies in the `alias` directive. This does not change the document_root, but it does change the file path that is used to serve the request. Unfortunately, `rewrite` and `try_files` tend to behave a bit unexpectedly with `alias`.

Let's start with a simple example - no PHP - just HTML and your Perl block - but with a folder structure matching yours (tested on Nginx 1.0.12, CentOS 6):

```
server {
    server_name example.org;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.access.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.pl last;
    }

    location ^~ /community {
        rewrite ^ /index.pl last;
    }

    location ~ \.pl {
        root   /var/www/vhosts/home;

        [fastcgi_stuff...]
    }


    location ^~ /news {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/news;
        index index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /news/index.htm;
    }

    location ^~ /app {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/app/app/webroot;
        index index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.htm;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /app/$1 last;
    }
}
```

- `location = /` - will only match the root path
- `location ^~ /community` - will match every path starting with /community
- `location ~ \.pl` - will match all files that contain .pl
- `location ^~ /news` - will match every path starting with /news
- `location ^~ /app` - will match every path starting with /app
- `location /` - will match all paths not matched above

You should be able to remove the `^~` - but it may offer a slight performance improvement, since it stops searching once a match is found.

While it should be a simple matter to add the PHP blocks back in, there is, unfortunately, a slight difficulty - `try_files` (and your rewrite) do not end up passing the desired path to the nested location block - and using `alias` when only the extension is specified in the location block doesn't work.

One solution is to use separate location blocks that perform a capture together with the alias directive - it isn't quite elegant, but as far as I can tell, it does work (again, tested on Nginx 1.0.12, CentOS 6 - of course, I didn't setup CakePHP, Wordpress, and Perl - I just used a couple of PHP and HTML files in each folder)

```
server {
    server_name example.org;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.access.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.pl last;
    }

    location ^~ /community {
        rewrite ^ /index.pl last;
    }

    location ~ \.pl {
        root   /var/www/vhosts/home;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/home.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/home.error.log;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.pl;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }

    location /news {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/news.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/news.error.log notice;
        alias /var/www/vhosts/news;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /news/index.php;
    }

    location ~* ^/news/(.*\.php)$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/news.php.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/news.php.error.log notice;
        alias /var/www/vhosts/news/$1;
        try_files "" /news/index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $1;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/vhosts/news/$1;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location /app {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/app/app/webroot;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log notice;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.php;
    }

    location ~* ^/app/(.*\.php)$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/news.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/news.error.log notice;
        alias /var/www/vhosts/app/app/webroot/$1;
        try_files "" /app/index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $1;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/vhosts/app/app/webroot/$1;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /app/$1 last;
    }
}
```

The above config, takes the simple one above, and makes two changes:

- Add two location blocks:

  - `location ~* ^/news/(.*\.php)$` - will match all files ending in .php, with paths starting with /news/
  - `location ~* ^/app/(.*\.php)$` - will match all files ending in .php, with paths starting with /app/
- Remove the `^~` matching - this is required so that the two added location blocks can match against paths (otherwise matching would stop on the /news or /app blocks).

It should be noted that the order for location matching is very important here:

- Exact matches first (using `=`)
- Matches with `^~` second
- Matching regex blocks
- Conventional strings - only if no matching regex is found

A matching regex will supersede a straight string!

An important point of mention is that when captures are used with alias, the entire URL is replaced - not just the leading folder. Unfortunately, this means that `$fastcgi_script_name` is left empty - so, I have used `$1` above instead.

I am sure you will need to make a few changes, but the basic premise should be functional. You should be able to separate the blocks into multiple files as needed - ordering shouldn't affect the config.

Comment: Dude, I wish I could upvote you 100 times. You're pure awesome. Thanks!